# What happens when you hit 200 reputation from upvotes in one day?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

I know there is a 200-reputation cap for upvotes in a single day. However, what happens when you get upvoted more on that day? Are the points simply lost? Or are they queued onto the next day? I'm just curious.

Comment: Rep beyond the cap is donated to hungry children in Africa.  It's kind of a jerk move on Jeff's part.  **How can they eat rep, Jeff?!**

Comment: @Pesto: The excess rep is ground into a power and, when combined with water, makes a sticky edible paste.  It doesn't taste very good, but it's very nutritious.

Comment: SOYLENT REP IS PEOPLE!

Answer (score 8):

The points are lost. The up-votes still count towards badges though (subject area badges, nice  question/answer etc.).

If some of the votes you did receive are rescinded for some reason (voter fraud, deleted question etc.) then a rep recalculation will be performed and the other votes you still have for that day used to calculate your new rep total. If you've exceeded the cap by more than the votes lost you won't notice the recalc.

Comment: Hm okay. That's fair, however I do notice sometimes that I'll just get points out of nowhere, and I don't mean because of accepted answers or anything.

Comment: Unless it's due to a recalc or a bonus for associating accounts then you'll have to ask the team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: There is a glitch in the fact that if cast a downvote, that -1 point will actually go against your daily rep limit, so not only will you lose 1 point, but your rep limit will be effectively reduced to 199 for the day. Welbog and myself tested this over the previous weekend and Welbog submitted it here on Meta.

Comment: Good to know TheTXI, because I KNOW that's happened to me.

Comment: I didn't cover the nuances mentioned by @jinguy and @TheTXI because I thought they might confuse the main point, so thank's for bringing them up.

Comment: It's only a glitch if you consider the cap to be `RepAtMidnightYesterday + 200`. If however, you think of it as the amount of rep other users can give you in a day or `(UpForYou * UpModifier) - (DownForYou * DownModifier)` then the rep cap looks consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet wrote a program that credits all the remainder reputation points to his account.

Comment: Office space...!!  Except Jon left the 'bug' in on purpose.

Comment: Wish I could have thought of that.  I should have paid more attention to Office Space.

Comment: Superman III, surely! (generation gap showing)

Answer (score 2):

Once you hit the reputation cap for the day you can still earn rep from accepted answers as well as bounties.

Only upvotes don't count after that point.