# My question is getting upvote but point not adding to my Rep, Why?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No reputation for upvote given?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/no-reputation-for-upvote-given)

My question is getting upvote but point not adding to my Rep, Why?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/recent-activity-vote-counts-are-missing-corrupt http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23787/how-did-i-get-5-points-for-2-upvotes-on-my-answer-on-so

Comment: A link to the question would be nice   ;)

Answer (score 1):

The two most likely answers are that you've hit your rep cap for the day, and that the question is community wiki.  Since you've posted hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow, and you don't give a clue as to which question, we're not going to be able to be more helpful than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have reached the maximum limit of 200 reputation per day*, then you will not acquire any more reputation for that day except for accepted answers and bounties.

*A day is defined as the 24 hour period between 00:00 UTC and the next occurrence of that time.

Comment: so will that point add later?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/what-happens-when-you-hit-200-reputation-by-upvotes-for-one-day
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct

Comment: No, you will not receive those points. However, you will be eligible to receive more reputation the next day.

Comment: Yes, you definitely reached the rep cap: http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=84201&mode=yesterday&showflair=true